# RESTful Spring for Android POST request

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson, http-post

I'm sending a GET request to a server.

```
private class DTOTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DTO> {
    @Override
    protected DTO doInBackground(Void... params) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        return template.getForObject(Constants.URL.GET_URL, DTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DTO dto) {
        List<DTO> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(dto);

        adapter.setData(data);
    }
}
```

It works.
How to send POST request?

Answer (score 0):

use any of this methods instead of `getForObject`

```
public <T> T postForObject(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables);

public <T> T postForObject(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> uriVariables);

public <T> T postForObject(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException;
```

Comment: @Arslanali what examples? just replace `getForObject` with `postForObject` and run the app.

Comment: The problem of how to pass a parameter in POST request (login and password).

Comment: @Arslanali create a `HashMap`, put these parameters and it and use second `postForObject` method. try to pass `null` or `new Object()` as `request` argument